# Sensu check-process.rb gives CheckProcess:OK for any -p pattern passed, which is not a current active process

Tags: sensu

[image: Check-process.rb for a regex 'abc']

There is no process named `abc`. I am pretty new to Sensu, please help is needed. The same check when executed on my sensu-client directly gives the following result:

```
root@pune-4755-col-stag-1:~# sudo check-process.rb -p /abc/ -W 1
```

> CheckProcess CRITICAL: Found 0 matching processes; cmd //abc//

```
root@pune-4755-col-stag-1:~# sudo check-process.rb -p abc -W 1
```

> CheckProcess CRITICAL: Found 0 matching processes; cmd /abc/

Comment: First of all, welcome to StackOverflow. Following the advices of the community, it is recommended to include context to your source code in order to receive the proper responses. 
Please check the documentation [on how to write a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What happens when you remove sudo from the command?There should be no reason for it here.